# JavaScript execute script when the screen width is < 480 and not when its grater than > 480?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey i have this small really easy script but i'm not js developer and i don't know how to fix this issue. I'm using bourbon and neat for front end of my site and i have one page when i want to use this collapse script which i took from bourbon refills. My question is how i can make this script to only work if screen width is lower than 480px if it is not lower than 480 don't execute this script?

HTML code

```
<div class="expander">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="expander-trigger expander-hidden">Expandable section</a>
  <div class="expander-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio mollitia fugiat facilis enim accusamus quisquam aut, repellendus incidunt quod optio facere labore illo numquam ipsum beatae vero debitis, fugit excepturi.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.expander-trigger').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("expander-hidden");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.expander-trigger').click(function(){
    if($(window).width() < 480) { // check width of window
      $(this).toggleClass("expander-hidden");
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT:
as per comment discussion, this is what you're really after

```
$(document).on('resize', function() {
    if($(window).width() < 480) { // check width of window
        //document smaller than 480
    } else {
        //document larger than 480
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the action should be if the screen.width < 480 use this collapse if its not don't use anything everything should be uncollapsed

Comment: if you're resizing your screen to check if it changes, it wont. you'd also have to put code into a resize event listener to make it revert back. without more, i cant really help. your initial question was to toggle a class if the window width was lower than 480 and the above would do that. it working or not would depend on the rest of your code and how you are intending for it to work

Comment: Yes you are right, how i can do that with resize? Because my main problem is to solve it to be normal responsive web site? I want when users resize their screens they will see different if screen size iz lower than 480 they will see this example with collapse and if screen size is grater than 480 they will see ordinary html and css page without any scripts just with some text and images. Tnx a lot!

Comment: I've added to my answer an on resize event. I'm not going to do all the work for you. For one i don't know all your requirements. hopefully it helps and good luck.